# How to call composable Alertdialog from non composable function

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-alertdialog

I wanted to check whether the phone is rooted or not. For that I wanted to check as soon as the app is clicked.

> ```
> @HiltAndroidApp class ShoppingApp : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
>
> override fun onCreate() {
>     super.onCreate() }
> ```

This is the first class which is called as soon as the app is launched. Inside this onCreate, I wanted to add check if device is rooted. If its rooted I want to show AlertDialog else navigate to next screen.

When adding composable AlertDialog, its throwing error @Composable should be called from the context of Composable.

In this case, how should I code.

Comment: I don't think it's a good practice to display a dialog in Application class. I think you should consider displaying the dialog inside an Activity.

Comment: @mrzbn has a point. However, I believe your question is lacking some helpful info. 

You may have to show your code to some extent (not necessarily exact but) to help others understand you better. 

Where are you calling the code, what code are you calling, and where is the error?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a State object in your Application class and make your composable observe that object from an Activity or Fragment.

```
class ShoppingApp : Application() {
    val isRootedState = mutableStateOf(false)

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        if (isRootedDevice()) {
            isRootedState.value = true
        }
    }
}

class ShoppingActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val isRooted = remember { (application as ShoppingApp).isRootedState }
            if (isRooted.value) {
                AlertDialog(
                   // AlertDialog params
                )
            }
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Accept this, there's literally nothing more to it.